# how does toplink session.refreshObject() handle one to many mappings?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, one-to-many, toplink

am using the `Session.refreshObject(Object o)` method to fresh an object that has a `getList()` method. This list is provided by toplink using a one to many mapping. When I refresh the object, I want this list to be refreshed too. Is this possible or I have to refresh something else?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`refreshObject` is equivalent to calling `ReadObjectQuery`.

If you want to refresh objects in cascade you can use `ReadObjectQuery.cascadePrivateParts()`. According to [the doc](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10464_05/web.904/b10491/oracle/toplink/queryframework/DatabaseQuery.html) this method

> Cascade the query and its properties on the queries object(s) and all
>   privately owned objects related to the queries object(s)

.

Comment: ok but am not using the toplink session directly, we have our own abstraction of it which has an instance of toplink session in it. so readobject query is difficult

Comment: Put a method which calls cascadePrivateParts() in your abstraction

Answer (score 0):

I depends on the mapping of the entity in the list. But if you want to actually refresh those objects you must do a

```
refreshObject(o.getList());
```

Comment: this will not work because i have not mapped a vector type object in toplink